# Which server gets the htaccess 301 Redirects?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Question about Apache redirects. If I am moving a site to a new domain, but most of the URLs are changing, do I put the 301 redirects on the new server or the old server or do I split them between servers? For example:

```
# This goes in .htaccess on old server:
301 Redirect http://myoldsite.com/ http://mynewsite.com

# This goes in .htaccess on new server:
301 Redirect /old-path-1 http://mynewsite.com/new-path-1
301 Redirect /old-path-2 http://mynewsite.com/new-path-2
301 Redirect /old-path-3 http://mynewsite.com/new-path-3
```

...etc.

Comment: You have to keep all 301 rules on the old server's root .htaccess

Comment: What about pages that don't map to the new domain? Will the 404s appear on the old domain? What if I just change the A record of the old site to point to the new site. My concern is that I may eventually cancel the hosting on the old site.

Comment: @anubhava - why? This process looks fine to me... Redirect old domain to new domain, and then on the new domain, map old paths to new ones to prevent 404s...

Comment: @MikeRockett: This process requires double 301 redirects and that is bad for SEO and performance

Comment: @jshock: You can stop hosting old server but do point old domain to new IP address first. Then  of course you can move all the 301 rules to new server.

Comment: So no SEO penalty switch IPs and put all redirects on the new server?

Comment: Right that approach should be fine for SEO